# Why public function can be accessed via static call - PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Please review below code. Though I have not define test method as static It can be access by A::test(). How it is possible? Is it bug in PHP?

```
class A {       
        public function test(){         
            echo __CLASS__;
        }
}
A::test(); //Print 'A'
```

If I try to access any public member inside test() method, It is giving me an error. See below.

```
class A {   
        public $name = 'jimit';
        public static function test(){          
                        echo $this->name;
            echo __CLASS__;
        }
    }
A::test(); //Error
```

Please help me out to clarify the things.

Thanks,
Jimit

Comment: The first example does produce an error, you just don't see it. Enable `E_STRICT` in your error reporting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug, but rather a leftover from PHP4's object model implementation. In current versions calling nonstatic method statically will raise an `E_STRICT` level warning.

As for the second one it is obvious, there's no instance of your class, so there is no `$this` to refer to.